How to keep ngx-translate translation files next to compiled electron app
I am building an Anguler-Electron App that uses ngx-translate for translation. The translation files are in the default folder assets/i18n.
I want the translation files to lay in a language folder that lays next to the executable after building so that the translation texts can be changed after building.
I've tried adding "assets/i18n/**/*" to the electron-builder.json under "files" but they did not show up in the built project folder. Also if they were, I wouldn't know how to change the translation file location for ngx-translate dynamically so that it uses the files from assets/i18n when in dev mode and the copied files when in production.

How about to load the Translations from a File-Server and Change it there?
So you can probably give access to others (your customers) and not risking any Security Issue
The Local translation on assets/i18n so are just a fallback then

@FloSojer I want it to work offline
